# Call function of Context in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-class-based-component

I have following Code in my `Context.js`:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import Reducer from "./Reducer";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};

export const Context = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
  }, [state.user]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now I want to use the Context in a class component and especially call the dispatch function, here a minimal example:

```
export default class Register extends Component {
  static contextType = Context;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.context;
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}
```

The Problem now is that `dispatch` is undefined, when I want to call it inside my class. Before I used the same context with `const { dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context);` inside a functional component and everything worked fine, what is the problem?

Comment: What does `console.log(this.context)` prints?

Comment: Just the initial state: `{user: null, isFetching: false, error: false}`

Comment: So it seems that your `Register` is not within `ContextProvider`

Comment: Okay, how do I add it there?

Comment: `ContextProvider` have to be an ancestor of `Register` component in the component tree

Comment: See for examples the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples), where `ThemeContext.Provider` is a parent of `Toolbar` (it doesn't have to be a direct parent)

Comment: I am passing the argument `children` to my ContextProvider, I thought this would add the components directly? I am sorry that I might mess a lot with this stuff but it's the first time I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments above, my `ContextProvider` has to be an ancestor of my `Register` component in the component tree. I simply added it inside my `index.js`:

```
...
import { ContextProvider } from "./context/Context";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <ContextProvider>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </ContextProvider>
);
```